# Get url query while return false

Tags: jquery

I've been searching for this on google en SO, i got the function that i wanted to get the query paramaters from the url ([link to article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.be/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)).
But i can't find an answer to my question, which i'm pretty positive about is that it should be prety easy to fix, i even feel foolish to ask, but i just can't find this specific answer.

When i click a link and i catch that click in jquery, the function returns false (i don't want a refresh), so the parameters that i want are not parsed into the url. How do i get these?

```
CURRENT URL: index.php?page=search&action=searchAll
<h4 class="videoLink"><a href="index.php?page=search&amp;action=playVideo&amp;isAjax=true&amp;v={$result.link}" class="{$result.link}">{$result.title}</a></h4>
```

jQuery simplified

```
$('.videoLink').click(playVideo);  

function playVideo(){
   url = getUrlVars();
   return false;
}

function getUrlVars(){
   var vars = [], hash;
   var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?')+1).split('&');

   for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
       hash = hashes[i].split('=');
       vars.push(hash[0]);
       vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
   }
return vars;
}
```

So when i trace url, i only get the params: page & action

Comment: Your url is wrong.. you never close the `href` tag

Comment: thats my bad, because the last parameter was a smarty variable and i changed it, just forgot to put the " back. my code is 100% valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before returning `false` you can get the link and extract the parameters..

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    var href = this.href;
    var params = {};
    // remove the part of the href up to the first ? character
    // and then split the remaining at the & character
    // loop the resulting list of somekey=somevalue
    // and split at the = and store in the params variable
    $.each(href.replace(/^.*?\?/gi,'').split('&'), function(i,val){
        var parts = val.split('=');
        params[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
    });

    // do what you want with the params here

    return false;
});
```

---

**Update**

If you want your code to work with the browser location as well as custom urls passed to it, you can change it to

```
function getUrlVars(href){
   var vars = [], 
       hash,
       url = href || window.location.href;

   var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?')+1).split('&');

   for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
       hash = hashes[i].split('=');
       vars.push(hash[0]);
       vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
   }
return vars;
}
```

and call it like this

```
function playVideo(){
   url = getUrlVars(this.href);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing that, the return false is always at the end of my statement. I will update my code so that it is more clear what i'm doing

Comment: @empi, your code tries to get the parameters from the URL. But since you return false the url does not change. You need to extract the parameters fromt he `href` attribute of the link, either use the code i provided, or alter your function to work with arbitrary urls passed as a parameter to it..

Comment: Thats the whole point of me posting this. These hrefs come from different places. In the example above it come's from the H4, so i'm using "link = $(this).children('a').attr('class');" (i've made classes for the links atm to read them out). When you can also click on a image, so therefore i have to make an if/else statement. Thats why i thought of using the href. So that it would be more dynamic and without the use of making classes. In this case i still have to use that if/else statement. Sorry if i didn't explained myself well enough. Still much thanks for your reply's!

Comment: but why bind to the `h4` and not directly to the link `a`. That way you can always have direct access to the href attribute of the link.. (*no need to put the url in the class*). The code i posted is dynamic and will extract the parameters regardless of where the link is..

Comment: Because i think this is better for Search Engine Optimalisation, to have a well built H structure in the website (these titles are youtube vids titles), but offcourse i'm not completely sure this will make alot of difference, but thats how i learned it in school. And for the image link, i could make the anker the size of the thumbnail and put the image underneath it instead of wrapping the image in the anchor, so i can acces the anchor directly. I will do it the way you say, its more efficiënt. Thanks for your help Gaby :)

Comment: you can have the link inside the `h4` for SEO purposes and still access it directly with `$('.videoLink a')` or just put the `videoLink` class directly on the `a` element ..